# ERROR/Web Console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getItem' of null at http://m.youtube.com/:844

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

The following error comes from Android (WebView) and not directly from my own code:

```
04-28 12:36:15.174: ERROR/Web Console(7604): 
  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getItem' of null at http://m.youtube.com/:844
```

I am really not doing anything special other than loading that URL into WebView. Most of the time I **don't** get this error, so I am assuming this could be pointing to some unreliable network conditions? Perhaps youtube.com too busy?

It's hard to tell. Regardless, I would like to at least have an idea what could be causing this and whether I can catch that error so that I can better handle it.

Again, my own code has no knowledge of what `getItem` is. On the other hand, when this problem occurs, the YouTube page on my WebView is simply **empty**.

Insights?

EDIT: I have been looking for documentation about the proposed `WebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)`. The only hint I have been able to find so far was [in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157184/android-making-webview-domstorage-persistant-after-app-closed): As I mentioned earlier, this problem occurs very rarely and haven't occurred since I posted my question. So I must understand a little more about the connection between this and "DOM storage" before I can devise a way to test/verify whether this solves the problem.

Also, I just encountered another error message (with benign results, so it seems):

```
05-02 00:44:45.823: ERROR/Web Console(1595): 
  dojo.back.init() must be called before the DOM has loaded. 
  If using xdomain loading or djConfig.debugAtAllCosts, 
  include dojo.back in a build layer. 
  at http://sj.example.com/ncscript/subsect/j_gs/version/20110428191502.js:164
```

I can now see some connection to DOM, so it looks like @Brian O'Dell is in the right direction. I just need to understand what `WebSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true)` does.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Perhaps you need something like:

> WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
>
> settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930623/webview-causing-uncaught-typeerror-when-loading-www-google-com)

Comment: @Brian O'Dell +1 for providing this clue. I will have to test this and get back with a definite reply. As I mentioned in my question, this error happens very rarely, so I need to verify your proposed fix over a period of time to make sure that this is indeed it.

Comment: @uTubeFan Any idea if that helped?

Comment: @Brian O'Dell Please see my edit. Any idea where I can find more information about what `setDomStorageEnabled(true)` does? Thanks.

Comment: @uTubeFan Could setDomStorageEnabled(true) be referring to this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Storage

Comment: @Brian O'Dell Thanks & +1 for the Wikipedia link (I mistakenly searched for DOM storage which may explain why I couldn't find what I was looking for). Also, I just implemented your suggested fix. I am tracking this now and will report back if it comes back. So accepting for now. :)

Comment: @uTubeFan good luck.  If you keep getting the error, maybe try to make it worse.  If you can make it happen more often, it will be easier to catch.

Comment: Guts help me on the same issue .I see that setDomStorageEnabled(true) does not work for the 1st time for a webview. Details are given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887986/android-webview-issue-for-twitter-even-with-domstorageenabled-enabled#comment15820454_11887986

Comment: Brilliant, Brilliant Brilliant!! That just worked! I think js was getting killed because of modifying the DOM and not getting a response in proper! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to use `localStorage` with `Chrome Custom Tabs` and I was getting the same error. I have used `window.localstorage` instead of `localStorage` and problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: unable to call null's 'getItem' method

I was using `localStorage.getItem` to retrieve the value, so I changed it to `window.localStorage.getItem` and fixed the problem