# Android web view is not loading the URL

Tags: android, webview

I have a problem on loading webview with the following [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator):

1. http://www.walmart.com/
2. http://mobile.walmart.com/

But both are showing an empty page in webview.

Here I have attached the source code. How do I come out of this problem?

Source:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

public class WEBVIEW_ITSELF extends Activity {

    WebView homeWeb;
    Button btnPlay;

    final Activity activity = this;
    static Context mContext;

    public boolean orandationChange = true;

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        orandationChange = false;
    }

    String urlchange;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.i_webview);

        mContext = this;

        homeWeb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.website_webview);
        homeWeb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        homeWeb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); // Zoom control on web (You)

        homeWeb.clearHistory();
        homeWeb.clearFormData();
        homeWeb.clearCache(true);

        WebSettings webSettings = homeWeb.getSettings();
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

        homeWeb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);

                if (progress == 100)
                    activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name); // To enable this you
                                                          // should not set
                                                          // android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                                                          // in the manifest file.
            }
        });

        homeWeb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                    String description, String failingUrl) {

                System.out.println(" failingUrl " + failingUrl);
                System.out.println(" description " + description);
                System.out.println(" errorCode " + errorCode);

                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl(url);

                return false;
            }
        });

        homeWeb.loadUrl("http://mobile.walmart.com/");
    }
}
```

Comment: have u give permisition   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  in Menifest ?

Comment: hi @parag . yeah i have added the permission .For Eg.,  if i will give the url  "http://www.google.com" means its loading ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm really not sure why (you can do some more research), but putting this in seems to make it work!

```
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

I found that here:

[ERROR/Web Console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getItem' of null at http://m.youtube.com/:844](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822256/error-web-console-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-getitem-of-null-at-h)

Comment: I found that by searching for the two errors from the logcat.

Comment: hi @leenephi i have another problem too with the following url . http://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwacapget.php?x=MA124CA0B5C008.RedFlagWarning.124CA0B6FD9CMA.BOXRFWBOX.835121ef7181220c68e2838a75b2cb97           its not at all loading ... please help me . i have checked with  webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); also

Comment: I have search a lot and finally i found solution with your answer, thanks a lot.