# Android Webview issue for Twitter even with DomStorageEnabled enabled

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have tested the following issue on Galaxy Note 2.3, Sony tablet 3.2 as well as Galaxy Y 2.3 and the issue is 100% reproducable. As suggested on many threads , `webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);` does the trick. But i am observing that first time when the Webview loads twitter.com , its going blank . Then if i say `webview.reload()` or again call load Url then twitter loads correctly every time until i exit the app (Preferably Force stop from settings) . This issue is happening for all sites which give WebConsole error. If i reload the same site , then its loading correctly. Is anyone having the same issue ?

Following is a small snippet of code  i use.

```
webview = new Webview(activity.context);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); 
webview.loadUrl("http://www.twitter.com");
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, in this blank state have you tried zooming or panning to see if the rendering kicks back in?  You might try loading up the Hierarchy Viewer and taking a look at the state of the WebView.

Comment: I tried zooming or panning but it  doesnt help. I know what you mean by that . I have also observed that on some sites. I could solve that issue by adding following webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); If i could trap the WebConsole error given by Webview , that might help. 
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
Also ,Unfortunately my device is not getting connected to Heirarchy Viewer. But i am surprised why hasnt anyone reported seeing this issue yet. Wondering where i am going wrong.

Comment: People have solved the WebConsole issue as given here . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822256/error-web-console-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-getitem-of-null-at-h But its not working 1st time. Very irritated to say this again and again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardcoding the Useragent as suggested on other threads solved the problem

```
webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
```

What will be the disadvantages of this dirty trick ? Will it affect the sites loading on a tablet ?
Will users be able to go to the desktop site if they want to ?