# Android webview unable to launch instagram login

Tags: android-webview, instagram-api

We have an app where we allow the user to login via instagram.

Currently, we launch the url:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
```

But we are noticing that on android devices, there is a javscript error being thrown. And the user will be stuck on a white screen.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null
    at o.r.componentDidMount (/static/bundles/base/LoginAndSignupPage.js/bf549b389501.js:1)
    at nu (fd511240bc76.js:1)
    at tu (fd511240bc76.js:1)
    at Za (fd511240bc76.js:1)
    at Ya (fd511240bc76.js:1)
    at xa (fd511240bc76.js:1)
    at uu (fd511240bc76.js:1)
    at cu (fd511240bc76.js:1)
    at pu.render (fd511240bc76.js:1)
    at fd511240bc76.js:1
```

This just started happening today.

Upon further investigation, i think the webpage https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login simply does not work on any android webview.

Does anyone know how we can possibly resolve this problem? We have updated the system webview in our testing devices to the latest Android System Webview.

Anyone knows someone from Instagram to please address this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it may have been an issue with Chrome. We were able to resolve the issue by following the answer given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33080057/6200073

Comment: You are a god send. Not sure why it just stopped working this morning! Perhaps system chrome webview just decided to not enable storage by default