# How to fix white screen in webview_flutter?

Tags: android, webview, flutter

Run webview_flutter example app(https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/webview_flutter/example) with inital_url: "https://kreatryx.com"
On Android it just shows white screen with Zopim chat bar on the bottom right. On iOS it runs fine. 
Any solution for android?

What I've already tried:
1. Flutter channel dev
2. Flutter channel master

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Thanks to the [github Issues reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126568/2162226) in this post, the following solution worked for me to edit **Info.plist**:

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<string>YES</string>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <true/>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key> <true/>
</dict>
```

I am new to working with **Info.plist**, and wasn't sure if the `<dict>` tags could be nested like that, but apparently it's ok.

Comment: i did not work for me. I used another lib flutter_inappwebview, it works well.

Answer (score 7):

Incase the `url` you use is not all in English or has some spacial character. You need to encode the url like this

```
 WebView(
      initialUrl: Uri.encodeFull(yourUrl),
      ...
 )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what i need, stuck with this issue from last 6 hours

Answer (score 7):

For me, I needed to enable Javascript by setting:

```
javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted
```

```dart
WebView(
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        initialUrl: 'https://example.com',
)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

Full example using your URL:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: InAppWebViewPage()
    );
  }
}

class InAppWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InAppWebViewPageState createState() => new _InAppWebViewPageState();
}

class _InAppWebViewPageState extends State<InAppWebViewPage> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("InAppWebView")
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: InAppWebView(
                    initialUrl: "https://kreatryx.com",
                    initialHeaders: {},
                    initialOptions: InAppWebViewWidgetOptions(
                      inAppWebViewOptions: InAppWebViewOptions(
                        debuggingEnabled: true,
                      ),
                      androidInAppWebViewOptions: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
                        domStorageEnabled: true,
                        databaseEnabled: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                      webView = controller;
                    },
                    onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                    onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {

                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ]))
    );
  }
}
```

It works fine in both Android and iOS platform.
This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**update**

Similar to [Android Webview: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33079762/android-webview-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-getitem-of-null)

`settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);` is missing.

Related issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26347

**original**

webview_flutter does currently not automatically redirect.

`https://kreatryx.com` redirects to `https://www.kreatryx.com` and the plugin doesn't follow that redirect and just shows what `https://kreatryx.com` returns, which is nothing.

Follow https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25351

Comment: Android uses Chrome, iOS uses Safari, so different behavior is not a big surprise even though they are supposed to behave the same as far as possible.

Comment: My error is exactly the same as the error in above mentioned Android Webview issue. I just hope that settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true); fixes the issue. Anyway, thanks and I've updated my question with the screenshot on both the operating systems.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue using **original** answer, and posted my answer here for that.  Regarding the **update** , can you please explain how to get the instance for `settings` and where the call to `settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);` should be made .. is that in Flutter code, or in iOS code?  I was not able to find any reference on that so far.

Comment: @GeneBo https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1836/files might help

Answer (score 0):

As there is another plugin available which has the ability to automatically redirect to its requested page.
Use the given dart plugin: **flutter_webview_plugin 0.3.0+2**

You can use that plugin from this url: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin#-readme-tab-

Sample Code found here:

```
new MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
          url: "https://kreatryx.com",
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Widget webview"),
          ),
        ),
      },
    );
```

Comment: That is for the last resort. It's just that the plugin that you've mentioned works fine with a caveat that it floats over the flutter so snackbar or any such components hide behind it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try This Guys U Can Easily Preview PDF Getting From Response.
    
    Uint8List? _documentBytes;
    @override
    void initState() {
      getPdfBytes();
      super.initState();
    }
     
    ///Get the PDF document as bytes
    void getPdfBytes() async {
 Map<String, String> _header = <String, String>{
      'Authorization': _userDataController.userDataModel.token,
      'content-type': 'application/json',
    };
      _documentBytes = await http.readBytes(Uri.parse(
          'https://cdn.syncfusion.com/content/PDFViewer/flutter-succinctly.pdf' Or 'url'));
    headers: _header,
      setState(() {});
    }
     
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      Widget child = const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      if (_documentBytes != null) {
        child = SfPdfViewer.memory(
          _documentBytes!,
        );
      }
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter PDF Viewer')),
        body: child,
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue by changing a single line in NavigationDelegate.
Actually, it was causing an error in iOS White Screen.

```
 ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            // Update loading bar.
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {},
          onPageFinished: (String url) {},
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) async {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.somesite.com/')) {
              // do something...
            } else if(request.url.startsWith('http://someothersite.com/')){
              // prevent or do something else if this matches
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;  // <-- Set it to navigate
          },
        ),
      ),
```