# Alexa Account Linking using Google Sign-In fails on Alexa's Android App

Tags: google-signin, alexa-skills-kit

We have an Alexa Skill that needs to perform account linking using Google Sign-In.

Google Sign-in requires the browser's local storage which is disabled on the Alexa's Android App causing the account linking via Alexa's Android App to fail.

Is there a way to avoid Google Sign-in requiring local storage or a work-a-round that we could use to avoid this issue?

**-- Details --**

We can successfully link the account in the browser using Alexa's Website App (http://alexa.amazon.com/) but when using Alexa's Android App it fails.

When it fails we see the following error message in the Android logs:

`I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: https: //ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/o/2748322407-idpiframe.js (6)`

Based on this answer [ERROR/Web Console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getItem' of null at http://m.youtube.com/:844](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822256/error-web-console-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-getitem-of-null-at-h), the error happens when the local storage setting in the Android App is disabled and suggests enabling it. We cannot enable it since this is Alexa's Android Application.

We confirmed that the access to local storage was the issue by blocking local storage in the web browser and then by trying account linking using Alexa's Website App (http:// alexa.amazon.com/) and we see the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Very helpful. Do you have code in GitHub that shows how you are acheiving the Google Account linking? Having some trouble getting past a redirection_url error when using account linking to Google

Comment: I got this to work by using the flow specifying the 'redirect_uri' in the parameters with the URI of my server's authorization code handler.

For details see: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow