# Android API 23. WebView how to ignore javascript errors

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Im using WebView to embed a third party website into an app.

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
mWebView.loadUrl("http://someurl.com/");
```

The problem is WebView freezes as it finds javascript errors:

> I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(7178)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null"

but somehow in the browser (Android), it loads perfectly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try to use **setDomStorageEnabled(true)**

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930623/webview-causing-uncaught-typeerror-when-loading-www-google-com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930623/webview-causing-uncaught-typeerror-when-loading-www-google-com)

Comment: Thanks a lot I din't know what was causing my webview to not load and this helped me