# Android chromium errors

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an android app which has webview to perform social login via Instagram. 
When i try to load the following url: 
"https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=ba231a873ea145af9f97866de4718fe6&redirect_uri=https://instagram.com/&response_type=token&display=touch&scope=public_content" 
some chromium errors shows up. 
With the knowledge that it's works fine When i try to load the same url via usual browser.

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The Content-Security-Policy directive 'worker-src' is implemented behind a flag which is currently disabled.
", source: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_authentication=1&only_user_pwd_authentication=1&platform_app_id=&next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fclient_id%3Dba231a873ea145af9f97866de4718fe6%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A//instagram.com/%26response_type%3Dtoken%26display%3Dtouch%26scope%3Dpublic_content (0)

I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(15)] "The key "viewport-fit" is not recognized and ignored.", source: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_authentication=1&only_user_pwd_authentication=1&platform_app_id=&next=/oauth/authorize/%3Fclient_id%3Dba231a873ea145af9f97866de4718fe6%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%3A//instagram.com/%26response_type%3Dtoken%26display%3Dtouch%26scope%3Dpublic_content (15)
```

Any ideas to fix this problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have to add this call

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

It's a duplicate of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930623/webview-causing-uncaught-typeerror-when-loading-www-google-com)